# understanding slow.log mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mysql slow.log output.
The query mysql slow is showing this and i checked the same with mysql `explain` and it said only 5 rows are examined but mysql slow say approx 7 lkh rows are examined.

In addition in my query there is nowhere written `set timestamp`

```
   # User@Host: dba[dba] @ localhost []
   # Query_time: 7.282718  Lock_time: 1.291532 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 651223
   SET timestamp=1361437845;
   SELECT *
   FROM tableA
   WHERE app='pic' and sub
   LIKE '%katrina%'
   order by id desc limit 5
```

here is explain output

```
    1 SIMPLE tableA index NULL  PRIMARY 4 NULL  5 Using where
```

Comment: Can you post the result your explain statement?

Comment: @TheVedge        1  SIMPLE  tableA  index  NULL PRIMARY  4  NULL 5  Using where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just 5 rows, because you're limiting the result set to 5 rows. See the last line of your query. Still MySQL has to examine those 651223 rows to find the result set from which it just displays 5 rows. This is because no index can be used on column `sub` because your LIKE clause starts with `%`. In case you have an index on column `app`, it may not be used for several reasons. Maybe you have too few distinct values compared to the number of rows your table is holding. So MySQL decides to use the primary key index for sorting (your order by clause). At least I assume so, because I can't really read your `explain` result in your comment. Edit such info into the question, please, next time.

The `SET timestamp=1361437845` is the time when the query was executed as unix_timestamp.

**UPDATE (explained further):**

Your LIKE clause is `LIKE '%katrina%'`. This means "somewhere in the string is katrina, there might be characters in front of it and after it". Now imagine yourself you wanted to look someone up in the telephone book based on these criteria. The fact, that the telephone book is ordered alphabetically is useless, because the persons name might be Ankatrina or Zekatrina. Same with your index on column `sub`.

Imagine you have 3 million rows, 1 million rows of them have "pic" in column app, 1 million have "nic" and 1 million have "asdf". This would mean, that it's actually extra work to have a look in the index, then look up the actual record in the table. So it's sometimes cheaper to just scan the whole table. But like I said, that's just a guess. We don't have enough information about your database.

Having an index is no guarantee that the index will be used.

The reason why `EXPLAIN` says 5 rows but not slow-query-log is, that `EXPLAIN` is actually just a guess, how the optimizer might handle your query. When you want to know how it really will be handled use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. What is also a bit tricky here is, that the query wouldn't have to examine so much rows if you wouldn't `ORDER BY id DESC`. Then MySQL would really just scan 5 rows and spit out the result, because of your `LIMIT 5`. Because of your ordering it probably has to create a temporary table first, to sort things and from that table it spits out the 5 rows then. Might be that this is not considered in `EXPLAIN` but in `slow-query-log`.

Comment: i have index on sub as well as app so i think it should use index.one point i did not get .you are saying "You have just 5 rows, because you're limiting the result set to 5 rows"  i have used this query in mysql as well as in script .mysql explain says only 5 rows but slow.log says approx 7 lakh how????/as far as i know mysql explain gives near to perfect output

Comment: enjoyed reading ur explanation thanks. what you advise. i have to show the search and if i wont use % it wont show correct search as we dont know wht really user will search as per ur advise i will remove order by id but i think again it will search whole database

Comment: @wayenjoy You could have a look at fulltext indexes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: i tried but it is saying minimum 15 reputation required sorry

Comment: i tried with match and against for the query but it is not giving any result i have changed indexing to fultext also .can u plz tell what will be the equivalent fulltext query SELECT *
   FROM tableA
   WHERE app='pic' and sub
   LIKE '%katrina%'
   order by id desc limit 5

Comment: It would be something like `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE (sub) MATCH AGAINST 'katrina'`, but **it's important that you read the whole manual entry** for this. There are certain restrictions, like in MySQL versions beneath 5.6 it's only available for the MyISAM engine and so on. Make sure it really suits your needs. Databases in general are something you don't easily set up. You have to put much thoughts into it. It'll be the backbone of your whole application...

Comment: If you're looking for the whole text anyway, meaning your text is like an ID, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: fulltext is slow ????? or why you will not recommend as i am unable to display result with only like 'query%'   itried but its giving no result found with fulltext

Comment: It's not slow, but when you're always querying like `...WHERE app='pic'` or `...WHERE app='whatever'`, then a fulltext index might be too much overhead. Also, how have you tried? For example, there is no result when 50% of the rows contain the word that you're looking for. Then this word is considered "meaningless" or a stop word.

Comment: you are correct when i searched with bigger string it has given output.thx

Comment: @wayenjoy Found a blog in my thousand open tabs, stating that `LIMIT` is ignored in `EXPLAIN`. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/mysql-explain-limits-and-errors/ The guy usually knows what he's talking about :)